# C# HttpClient returns error 404 Not found

Tags: c#, http-post, dotnet-httpclient

Spent hours trying to figure this one out. Response Message always has a 404 Not found error. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
public static class BackendlessAPIHelper
{
    internal static string appId = "my-app-id";
    internal static string restSecret = "my-api-secret";
    internal static string backendlessBase = "https://api.backendless.com/";
    internal static string signupUrl = "v1/user/register";

    public static async Task<bool> UserSignup(string username, string password)
    {
        bool signupsuccessful = false;
        var client = new HttpClient();
        UserSignupBackendless newuser = new UserSignupBackendless { email = username, password = password };
        string newuserjson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newuser);

        try
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(backendlessBase);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("application-id", BackendlessAPIHelper.appId);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("secret-key", BackendlessAPIHelper.restSecret);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("application-type", "REST");
            StringContent theContent = new StringContent(newuserjson, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(backendlessBase+signupUrl, theContent);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                signupsuccessful = true;
                return signupsuccessful;
            }
            else
                return signupsuccessful;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.ToString();
            return signupsuccessful;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the API documentation: https://backendless.com/documentation/users/rest/users_user_registration.htm

I followed the article located here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2013/02/05/how-to-use-httpclient-to-post-json-data.aspx

Update: I realized the mistake. The signup URL was incorrect (missed a character).

Comment: You may want to check out [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), takes the guess-work out of debugging stuff like this.

Comment: Thanks @Aydin Adn. I'll definitely give that a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your base URL is getting duplicated:

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(backendlessBase);
// ...
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(backendlessBase+signupUrl, theContent);
```

You're specifying `backendlessBase` twice. If you already specified the base using `BaseAddress`, don't specify it again in the call.

Also if you read the docs carefully, it's `users/register`, not `user/register`.

Comment: I removed backendlessBase from the PostAsync call. it now has the signupUrl. Still returns the same error.

Comment: yep, I realized that just now. Thanks for pointing it out, @Matti Virkkunen.